# Jquery UI autocomplete JSON data parse

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Hey all I am trying to have my Jquery UI Auto-complete to take in a json string and have me able to only search from the first "Name" in the json and then be able to access the "image" part as well (i am inserting an image next to the name when it populates).

The json would look like this:

```
var availableData = [
   {"Name": "bob barker", "image": "./images/bbarker.png"},
   {"Name": "Jill bill", "image": "./images/jBill.png"},
   {"Name": "John Doe", "image": "./images/jdoe.png"},
   etc etc....
```

and the auto-complete script:

```
 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
 source: availableData,
 dataType: "json"
 })
```

But i need to change the jquery-ui-1.10.4.js file in order to be able to read the json since it normally took in an array.

Any help would be great!

An example would be [here](http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-json-example.html) but i cant seem to get that example to work with my code?

**update for irvin-dominin-aka-edward**

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
        .css({
              "background-image":"url('https://www.zzzzzz.com/photo?" + item.image + "')", 
              "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
              "background-position":"top left",
              "background-size":"30px 30px",
              "padding-left":"25px"
        })
        .appendTo( ul );
},
```

I am unable to get the "image" (using item.image) value.. I can get the "name" value just fine by doing **item.label**.

Comment: A fiddle will help answering your question

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, but the array elements should have `value` and `label` properties.

Comment: Check my OP update for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use jQuery [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate your starting item array or object to new array of items, than you can apply the input filter using [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/).

The current filter is stored in the `request`, [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) function parameter.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var availableData = [{
        "Name": "bob barker",
        "image": "./images/bbarker.png"
    }, {
        "Name": "Jill bill",
        "image": "./images/jBill.png"
    }, {
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "image": "./images/jdoe.png"
    }]

    $('#personsearch').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
            response($.grep(($.map(availableData, function (v, i) {

                return {
                    label: v.Name,
                    value: v.Name,
                    image: v.image
                };
            })), function (item) {
                return matcher.test(item.value);
            }))

        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ9xF/

Comment: Thats close but i need to be able to get the image data when it populates the name... check my OP for the code i am talking about.

Comment: I changed your code to reflect the needed data in order to retrieve it in the .js file. **image: v.image**